# Bootstrap Tabpanel Next Previous Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Tab Panel and it has long content so it would be better for the user to have next and previous buttons.

but they aren't working.

This is aspx code :

```
<div class="col_4">
<div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs" role="tabpanel" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs1" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#aboutmyself" id="aboutmyself-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="aboutmyself" aria-expanded="true">About Myself</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#familydetails" role="tab" id="familydetails-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="familydetails">Family Details</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#partnerpreference" role="tab" id="partnerpreference-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="partnerpreference">Partner Preference</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact" role="tab" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="aboutmyself" aria-labelledby="aboutmyself-tab">
            <!--Tab1 content-->
            <a class="btn-all btnNext" >Next</a>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="familydetails" aria-labelledby="familydetails-tab">
            <!--Tab2 content-->
            <a class="btn-all  btnPrevious" >Previous</a>
            <a class="btn-all btnNext" >Next</a>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="partnerpreference" aria-labelledby="partnerpreference-tab">
            <!--Tab3 content-->
            <a class="btn-all btnPrevious" >Previous</a>
            <a class="btn-all btnNext" >Next</a>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
            <!--Tab4 content-->
            <a class="btn-all btnPrevious" >Previous</a>
         </div>
```

And here is the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btnNext').click(function () {
        $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    });

    $('.btnPrevious').click(function () {
        $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use `tab` feature of bootstrap, it's would be better
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: nice suggestion, but i can't change the design because me and my friend are in a group and he made the design :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17475/)**

You code works fine you should just put it inside `ready` function :

```
$(function(){
    $('.btnNext').click(function () {
      $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    });

    $('.btnPrevious').click(function () {
      $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    });
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you , How stupid am i ! :) . well i upvoted but i have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: Would it be possible to scroll the page so that the tabs appear at the top of screen? Please send modified js

Comment: Thanks. Well i want user to click next button or previous button to get to the respective tab and vertical scroll to top so that the ul tabs is on the top of screen.